# Creating content via PHPMYADMIN

Tags: 8, database, migrations

I'm trying to add content to my Drupal 8 from the PHPMYADMIN.

You may be wondering *Why this way?* The fact is that I have a web in Drupal 6 and I tried a lot to migrate using the tools Drupal has, without success.

I'm not so good at programming, and the time is passing, so I decided to try the manual approach.

I created an article and inspected the database and saw what tables where altered to discover which tables where affected when I create an article.

Then I proceeded to manually create them.

The involved tables where:

- node
- node_revision
- node__body
- node_revision__body
- node__comment
- node_revision__comment
- node_field_data
- node_field_revision
- node__field_tags
- node_revision__field_tags
- taxonomy_term_field_data
- taxonomy_index
- taxonomy_term_data
- taxonomy_term_hierarchy
- comment_entity_stastics

I noticed that "menu_tree" and "cache_entity" are altered when creating an article, but I do not know how to manually insert data there because they have blob data.

After that, I re-built the cache, but the content I created wouldn't show.

I wonder if there are some tables I'm missing, or if with this method I won't be able to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish.

If I have to choose between spending time in trying to learn something hard for me (something I don't know if will be or not 100% a success) and manually creating the 1500 articles with the Drupal 8 UI, then I would stick with the second option, because manually creating content is 100% secure and won't consume my desire to live the way the alternatives I'm trying with no effort are doing.

But there may be something. to automatize the process at least a bit. Is there?

What should I do?

I wonder if investigating the import.php as some kind of method to which I can pass and array of info and achieve what I'm trying to do!

Ps: I have already tried with the Migrate, Migrate Plus, etc with no result.

Answer (score 5):

Don't even bother. This level of effort is not even necessary.

If you are just moving content from Drupal 6 to Drupal 8, use the built in Migration modules that come with core. It is *designed* to do this. I can't even quantify how long this would take to do in PHPMYADMIN of all things. You'd likely wind up corrupting the database itself. The schema is nowhere near as simple as it once was.

Please try using the tools and check the docs for more: https://www.drupal.org/node/2257723

All you have to do is point it at your Drupal 6 database and let it work. If you have basic content (sounds like Articles and blog posts) it should work very well. It will even build out the content type and taxonomy for you.

Even if the automatic route doesn't totally work, still attempt to use the Migration tools available to you. You will save a ton of hours (probably hundreds) vs editing a database manually.

Comment: Thanks for your advice..

I tried with Migrate tool and got the info imported to the DB, however I had errors with some tables (some messages saying that those tables won't be migrated). But the main problem is that the links are wrong,
The page looks like all was imported right, but when I click... it leads to the old URL.  
Trying to harcode the node into the URI didn't solve it (ex. http://example.com/node/210).
Without that working, the migration is a failure

Comment: Getting all the content in is step one. The second step is addressing things like that. Yes, links in WYSIWYG fields may need to be updated, and there is probably a migration strategy for that that someone like mikeryan could speak to. I would do a mysql find and replace, personally. If it is a matter of paths and aliases not working, that doesn't mean the migration is a failure. Are the aliases even generated?

Comment: Thank you very much. No the aliases where not being generated. 
I tried with Migrate CSV and although it's a bit hard, it is the way to do it.. 
I will stick with your recomendations I find them useful

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you would be to export somehow the data you have into CSV, and then use a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds to import your content.

Comment: Thank you very much and thanks for the edit =)
Unfortunately is not possible for me since Feeds is still not developed into Drupal 8 , but this may be the solution in the future